# How to access key name in json_string type of Shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

For example I have this JSON string in `product_supplier['shipping_to']`:

```
{"United States": {"time": "1-3"}, "Worldwide": {"time": "10-15"}}
```

How can I access the country name in liquid? Tried this:

```
{% for country, time in product_supplier['shipping_to'] %}
  {{ country }}: {{ time['time'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Which obviously doesn't work as it gives error: `Liquid syntax error: Syntax Error in 'for loop' - Valid syntax: for [item] in [collection]`

And tried this:

```
{% for country in product_supplier['shipping_to'] %}
  {{ country[0] }}, {{ country[1] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Which gives empty output with just a comma:

```
,
```

From the official doc [here](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/metafield), it seems it's only able to access the values not keys?

Comment: I think this string format and you need to check with string filter [link](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/string-filters), array loop is not working in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you saved the metafield as json_string then you can do this.

```
{% for item in product.metafields.product_supplier.shipping_to %}
 {{item[0]}}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

The response will be:

```
United States
Worldwide
```

Once again this must be as json string to work.

So it similar to your third example but we are using the proper object (in this case `product.metafields`) to target that metafield.

Tested it on my end it works without a problem.

Comment: But how to output the value part? e.g. {"time": "1-2"}

Comment: @datasn.io The same way using the `item[1]` => `{% for sub in item[1] %}{{sub[0]}}{{sub[1]}}{% endfor %}` or directly `item[1].time`.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I'm not sure what's wrong: `{% assign shipping_to = product_supplier['shipping_to'] | json_parse %}
{% for item in shipping_to %}
 {{ item[0] }}<br/>
{% endfor %}`

Comment: How do I make sure product_supplier['shipping_to'] is actually a json_string type rather than just a string? It seems it's just a string.

Comment: @datasn.io you need to save the metafield type as `json_string`, you can't do this just by adding a json, this should be an option in the Metafield app you are using. Refer to https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/metafield `value_type` property, which can be `string`, `integer` or `json_string`.